# Assigning user permissions with post_save signal

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-signals

I have a custom User model called `EmailUser` and I'm trying to assign a custom model permission on `post_save`. I have the following signal in models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=EmailUser)
def assign_permissions(sender, **kwargs):
    emailUser = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view polls')
        emailUser.user_permissions.add(permission)
        print emailUser.user_permissions.all()
```

The print statement returns the expected: `[<Permission: polls | poll | Can view polls>]` but when I look at the user in admin the permission is not selected and when I check it in shell, the permissions are empty.

Comment: Could you try `emailUser.save()` before adding the permission to the user.

Comment: @pythonista: Just tried that. Same exact behavior.

Comment: @oppositeday did you figure out a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @newdimension: Sadly, no. I ended up having to use a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, I tried to use `post_save`|`pre_save`|redefining `save()` model method|redefining `model_save()` method in `admin.py` file, but I didn't get the expected behavior(don't see selected permissions in the admin interface)

So I started investigating this question and found in `django.contrib.admin.options` file, `ModelAdmin` class, `_changeform_view` method the next code:

```
self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
```

So firstly instance is saved by `save_model` and then permissions are rewritten by `save_related`

So I just redefined `changeform_view` in my `UserAdmin` class

My redefined code listing  is the next:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        to_field = request.POST.get(TO_FIELD_VAR, request.GET.get(TO_FIELD_VAR))
        obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id), to_field)
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=obj.id)
        if user.is_lab_director:
            permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can change job')
            user.user_permissions.add(permission)
        else:
            user.user_permissions.clear()

        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)):
            return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

I hove this help someone to solve such question

Comment: Sorry, but how do you use save_related? In my code I have to put the permissions based on business   rules  after Admin creates a staff user. My code https://dpaste.org/Ccds